# Browserify doesn't translate module.exports to window property?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, browserify

I'm very confused by the use-case of browserify at the moment. I had always been under the impression that it would take an `npm` module and make it use-able in the browser. However if I take a standard `npm` module, run it through browserify, and include it in a webpage, I find the module is completely inaccessible.

node module:

```
console.log('wtf');
function SayHi() {
  return 'hello world';
}
module.exports = SayHi;
```

run it through browserify:

```
browserify test.js > browserify_test.js
```

Now when I include it in a simple webpage and open the JS console I see:

```
"wtf"
```

however cannot access the module:

```
> SayHi
ReferenceError: SayHi is not defined
```

in order to access my module I need to add some boilerplate code to my `npm` module:

```
... (previous test.js code)...
if (typeof window === 'object') {
  window.SayHi = SayHi;
}
```

now, after passing through browserify and loading the page, I have access to my module:

```
"wtf"
> SayHi
function SayHi()
> SayHi()
"hello world"
```

I thought the whole point of browserify was to make your modules usable in the browser. Not just run them in a sandbox and not let you get to the module itself. Before I go about adding that boilderplate addition to all my modules, I thought it best to ask here to make sure I'm not missing something fundamental.

I also don't see how this is supposed to work in an AMD environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.forbeslindesay.co.uk/post/46324645400/standalone-browserify-builds

You need the `--standalone` option.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. You'd think for such a fundamental piece of the puzzle this would be mentioned in the numerous introduction examples. Including the browserify main page and docs themselves.

Comment: @nick-jennings over a year later, and this had me scratching my head for over half an hour. for a tool called "browserify", this does feel like a vital piece of information, because when the docs state "run this command and just stick the output in your html, and you're done", i expect to be able to actually run my code on that page.